# Получить JSON по url android

Tags: java, android, json, api

Приложение под андроид. Нужно получить JSON по ссылке.
Знаю как создать соединение:

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        // create connection
        URL urlToRequest = new URL(serviceUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();

     ------ сode here ---------

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Знаю, что есть метод getContnet() для urlConnection, но при его вызове получаю ошибку:

```
    W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c8db20)
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Вот инфа от сервера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Status 304

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить JSON?

Comment: Какое сообщение ошибки? Проверьте, во-первых не забыли ли вы указать в манифесте разрешения для подключения к интернету, и во вторых запрос к серверу с недавних пор запрещено вызывать в основном потоке, так что для запроса делайте отдельный поток

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получение JSON'a

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(http://someJSONUrl/jsonWebService);
// Depends on your web service
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = null;
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    inputStream = entity.getContent();
    // json is UTF-8 by default
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // Oops
}
finally {
    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
}
```

**Создание JSON объекта:**

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

**Получение строки:**

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("STRINGNAME");
```

**Получение булева значения:**

```
boolean aJsonBoolean = jObject.getBoolean("BOOLEANNAME");
```

**Получение инта:**

```
int aJsonInteger = jObject.getInt("INTEGERNAME");
```

**Получение лонга:**

```
long aJsonLong = jObject.getBoolean("LONGNAME");
```

**Получение значения с плавующей запятой:**

```
double aJsonDouble = jObject.getDouble("DOUBLENAME");
```

**Получение массива:**

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("ARRAYNAME");
```

**Получение объектов с массива:**

```
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // Pulling items from the array
        String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("STRINGNAMEinTHEarray");
        String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("anotherSTRINGNAMEINtheARRAY");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Oops
    }
}
```

Comment: Уже все поставил, спасибо вам! А скажите, почему именно такая реализация? Почему никто не делает через HttpURLConnection?

Comment: С этим я вам не подскажу, так как я на этом языке не разрабатываю :)

Answer (score 2):

Если вдруг кому-то нужна реализация именно с использованием HttpURLConnection, то делюсь ссылкой: http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/